# A textbook on linear algebra where involutions on linear spaces are considered

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

Let us call an *involution* on a complex linear space $X$ an arbitrary $\mathbb R$-linear map $x\in X\mapsto x^*\in X$ that satisfies the following identities:
$$
x^{**}=x,\qquad (\lambda\cdot x)^*=\overline{\lambda}\cdot x^*\qquad (\lambda\in{\mathbb C},\quad x\in X).
$$
This is strange, I can't find a textbook on linear algebra where this notion is considered. Can anybody recommend something? I need a reference for some elementary facts like "$X$ is a complexification of the subspace of real elements" (i.e. elements satisfying the equality $x^*=x$), or "the dual space (of $\mathbb C$-linear functionals) also has a natural involution", etc.

P.S. I asked this also at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135977/a-textbook-on-linear-algebra-where-involutions-on-linear-spaces-are-considered).

Comment: I think you want a book that has coordinate-free definition of a complex structure on a vector space.

Comment: @zyx: this is strange, I can't find anything

Comment: See also [C$^*$-algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C*-algebra)

Comment: @lhf in my situation, the involution is considered on a vector space, without multiplication.